# lxml/beautifulsoup: Extracting text between two different tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have an "XML" document with a whole bunch of stuff like this:

```
Here is some text about a frog.  <hello ref="1"/>This frog is <hello ref="2"/>orange<goodbye idref="2"/> and has polka-dots.<goodbye idref="1"/>  Isn't this interesting?
```

From this, what I need is:

1. This frog is orange and has polka-dots.
2. orange

Short of doing something crazy with regular expressions, is there a way to do this The Right Way using some combination of `lxml` and/or `BeautifulSoup`?  Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through the [next siblings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings) of the `hello` tag with `ref="1"` until you meet `goodbye` element with `idref="1"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

data = """
<data>Here is some text about a frog.  <hello ref="1"/>This frog is <hello ref="2"/>orange<goodbye idref="2"/> and has polka-dots.<goodbye idref="1"/>  Isn't this interesting?</data>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "xml")

text = ""
for elm in soup.find("hello", ref="1").next_siblings:
    if elm and elm.name == "goodbye" and elm.get("idref") == "1":
        break

    text += elm.get_text() if isinstance(elm, Tag) else elm

print(text)
```

Prints:

```
This frog is orange and has polka-dots.
```

Comment: Yup, that does it.  Thanks!  In hindsight I'm not sure why I had a such a hard time figuring this out lol.

Answer (score -2):

Xml parsing from the standard library.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Uh, is there something I've been missing in the documentation that you'd like to point out to me?

Comment: The Doc are pretty clear, use the parse function to parse the doc then pull the elements that you want.